# Meaning of “Irish true”

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, word-order, signage

This is a sign from a pub. I would expect it to read “Irish truth” or “true Irish”. Why is “Irish true” used?

[image: sign]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an advertising slogan, not a considered argument, so it could be simply that 'Irish true' rhymes with 'Irish Dew'.

Comment: Good point. It's probably a combination of both. Effective advertising will hook different viewers different ways.

Answer (score 6):

Part of the answer is that it's an [advertising campaign](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/tullamore-dew-launches-irish-true-campaign-in-the-united-states-133873768.html) trying to brand a product as distinctively Irish. Ireland is historically noted for good whiskey.

I think they mean *authentic from an Irish viewpoint* or *quintessentially Irish* just as a leprechaun is *Irish true* but a Viking isn't.

Comment: I suspect that the agency which came up with this campaign may have been trying to achieve a less clichéd and more striking slogan than "True Irish" by exploiting Erse syntax, which ordinarily puts the adjective after the noun.

Comment: @StoneyB Very interesting. I don't know anything about Erse. Do you have a link to further information? Google keeps thinking that I'm misspelling erase.

Comment: "Erse" is sort of pretentious on my part; I use it to make clear I'm talking about Irish Gaelic rather than Irish English. Google "Irish language" and you will find all you want.

Comment: It's years since I've seen anybody refer to _Erse_. All reliable modern sources call the language _Irish_.